# hibernate generator increment conflict with table auto increment

Tags: hibernate, generator

I set generator as 'increment' in hbm file, and also i put auto_increment thing in database table also. 
   This creteria showing issue ....

This both thing is conflicting ? ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes they are conflicting, makes no sense..

When using hibernate built-in generator 'increment', it's hibernate that generate the identifiers by counting from the maximum primary key value at startup, not safe in multi JVM and using the database AUTO_INCREMENT it's the database that generate a unique identity for new rows.

In mySQL DB, if using AUTO_INCREMENT you should use identity in your mapping to let the database safely generate unique identity.

From hibernate documentation

**increment**

> Generates identifiers of type long, short or int that are unique only
>   when no other process is inserting data into the same table. Do not
>   use in a cluster.

**identity**

> supports identity columns in DB2, MySQL, MS SQL Server, Sybase and
>   HypersonicSQL. The returned identifier is of type long, short or int.

More information
[Hibernate Doc section 5.1.4.1. Generator](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id)
[My sql AUTO_INCREMENT documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)