# How to use save methoda with Hibernate annotations without incremented value?

Tags: hibernate

i try to use save() method, but the database schema doesn't have incremented value for Id, so it's giving Exception:
 ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save()

so i want to do it, how can i do this?

Comment: Question is vague and confusing. Not clear whether the question is about Hibernate schema generation, persisting entities or using Hibernate with databases which do not support auto-incrementing PK column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use @GeneratedValue annotation and specify the GenerationType IDENTITY.

```
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
public Long getId() { ... }
```

Read more at http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/

Comment: yes, it will because when you use IDENTITY then you have to manually set the value of id field.

Comment: what i want is:without Annotation we use Save() method that time it returns the Id right?
same way i want using annotations..and my column should not be auto_increment

Comment: As you said your column should not auto_increment but you want to use save method, so according to http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#save(java.lang.Object) this method returns object with auto generated identifier or in case of IDENTITY(or assigned) generator will use existing ID.

Comment: Yes i understand but, look i am creating this column using hbm.xml
<id type="long">
<column name="msgId" precision="22" scale="10"/><generator class="increment" />

Here column is created by Hibernate itself(without auto_increment) 
and i am using Save(), so it is returning  me id..everything is fine.
But, when i use the same schema with Annotation like :
!@Id
 !@GeneratedValue
 @Column(name = "msgId")
 @Type(type = "long")
 public Long msg;
 public String msgID;
it's giving Exception: id is null

Comment: Read this link - http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html . It explains about generator values.

Comment: Because you have not specified a strategy. @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.......)

Comment: @AlanHay by-default it takes incremented

Comment: I am not exactly sure what your question is. Is the relevant column in the database set to auto-increment or not?

Comment: look i am creating this column using hbm.xml <id type="long"> <column name="msgId" precision="22" scale="10"/><generator class="increment" /> Here column is created by Hibernate itself(without auto_increment) and i am using Save(), so it is returning me id..everything is fine. But, when i use the same schema with Annotation like : !@Id !@GeneratedValue @Column(name = "msgId") @Type(type = "long") public Long msg; public String msgID; it's giving Exception: id is null

Comment: Using hbm.xml:
+---------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| msgId   | bigint(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| message | longtext   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

Comment: Using Annotations:

+---------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| msgId   | bigint(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| message | longtext   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

Comment: SO, when i use save method with old schema(hbm.xml one) then it says msgId is null

Comment: This post could be useful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6776308/hibernate-generator-increment-confict-with-table-auto-increment

Comment: So what exactly are you asking? Why Hibernate DDL did not create the table with auto-increment for your table when using hbm.xml rather than annotations?

Comment: @code13..i get that, but still i don't understand how can i save method work using annotation without assigning the id's values manually

Comment: In that case you have to use @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id; and check your hibernate dialect is configured correctly.

Comment: @code13 i done this, but still not happening.
Exception: Field 'msgId' doesn't have a default value

Comment: what database you are using? and please your question with hibernate dialect configuration so that others can also give some directions.

Comment: Sorry, please revise your original question as I am not sure what the issue is. As far as I can determine you are asking why save does not work when using the increment strategy on a table without an auto-increment PK field. Well the obvious answer to that is to update your database table to have an auto-increment PK.

Comment: i am using MysqlDialect, and @AlanHay i want save() method to work with old schema that doesn't have auro_increment column

Comment: Well as I pointed out in my original answer if you do not have an auto-increment column then you will need to either (a) add one or (b) use another ID generation strategy. So please read the link and choose a strategy based on your requirement.

Comment: @AlanHay Okay i'll do that, one more thing,i define id in hibernate.hbl.xml as "increment" but in database table column doesn'y have auto_increment..why so??

Answer (score 0):

There are various other options available for key generation.

See here:

[How to choose the id generation strategy when using JPA and Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10041938/how-to-choose-the-id-generation-strategy-when-using-hibernate)